# Quote multiple words in a selection for insert statement

Tags: sql, vim, text, cygwin, notepad++

I'm looking for a quick way to quote words in a selection, like if I were to build many insert statements from a block of text separated by tab or space character.

Lets say I have

```
STUFF   OPEN    F   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
STUFF   OPEN    M   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:58
STUFF   OPEN    R   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
STUFF   OPEN    S   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
STUFF   OPEN    T   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
STUFF   OPEN    U   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
STUFF   OPEN    W   0   0   00:00:00-23:59:59
```

I want to get

```
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "F" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "M" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:58"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "R" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "S" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "T" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "U" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
"STUFF" "OPEN"  "W" "0" "0" "00:00:00-23:59:59"
```

In one click or less. In np++ I had to do find replace 3 times, just wondering if I could do this quickly with less manual labor? (Like select, click, done.)

I have vim, notepad++, Eclipse, VS 2013

No emacs, though I would be willing to give it a shot if I can run it in cygwin and do this kind of thing faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vim, you could use this substitution:

```
:%s/\S\+/"&"/g
```

which reads as "on every line in the buffer (`:%`), substitute every (`s/search/replace/g`) one or more (`\+`) non-whitespace character (`\S`) with a double quote (`"`), followed by the matched string (`&`), followed by a second double quote (`"`)".

Comment: cannot believe the answer with 20 mouse clicks and 1 meter mouse movement got more upvotes than this short and straightforward vim one. +1 !  @Nik if you plan to use vim, you won't miss notepad, notepad+, notepad++ or notepad+\+

Comment: Yeah vim is awesome, I was going to wait a bit to see what other answers would come up, but i just tried this out and damn it's fast. +1 Go vim

Comment: @Kent This answer definitely seems more suitable for OP but 20 mouse clicks? The other answer could be achieved with ~14 keystrokes and no mouse involved. Roughly the same amount of effort in my opinion.

Comment: @JonM if you count it carefully, it is not 14, it is 17. since you need `<cr>ZZ` to execute the cmd and save the file.  ok, maybe  one can achieve it with 10 mouse clicks, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++

Make sure the cursor is at the start of the file, press ctrl+h and select regular expressions. Use the expression `(\S+)` with `"\1"`

If you have to do this more than once you can go into `Macro` > `Start Recording` and perform the replace `Stop Recording`. After that you can save it and give it a shortcut (or press ctrl+shift+p to playback current macro).

Comment: This is pretty cool too, my only issue, while it works with ctrl+shift+p, when i use the shortcut i set for it ctrl+shft+q (for quote), it does not run the macro... i will +1 your answer if you tell me how to make this work :) if i go to macro and click on the macro, it works...